# Android enforce passcode lock?

Tags: android, enterprise, mdm

Is it possible to deploy a mobile profile on an Android device that enforces the use of a pass-code lock by the end user? Similar to how with iOS devices a company can deploy a mobile configuration XML file which enforce settings like the pass-code lock requirement. Is there an equivalent of this for android ? If so which versions of android support this?
Thank you.

Comment: if you find a useful answer, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. the way you do it is to use Android's [device admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) facility.

> Android 2.2 introduces support for enterprise applications by offering
>   the Android Device Administration API. The Device Administration API
>   provides device administration features at the system level. These
>   APIs allow you to create security-aware applications that are useful
>   in enterprise settings, in which IT professionals require rich control
>   over employee devices.

in a nutshell, you send the user through a short workflow that ask them to approve your app's activity as a device admin, then you can you use the [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) API to define security policies for the device (such as password policy).

the first link i provided is very good and it walks you through the whole process, so i won't try to duplicate that here.